# Freebase searchAPI return types

Tags: java, freebase

Is it possible to return the [type of an entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQtHP.jpg) (e.g Location)
just like how the [freebase search](http://www.freebase.com/search?query=bukit%20panjang&any=/common/topic) works? I am using freebase search sample codes (I'll provide them below) to generate the search results but even using the wildcard, it does not extract the entity types, here are some of the sample results.

**SAMPLE RESULTS**

```
["\/en\/bukit_panjang","Bukit Panjang",284.883636,"\/m\/04fxxf","en"]
["\/en\/bukit_panjang_mrt_station",{"id":"\/metropolitan_transit\/transit_stop","name":"Transit Stop"},"Bukit Panjang LRT\/MRT Station",250.857147,"\/m\/0661mk1","en"]
["\/en\/bukit_panjang_plaza",{"id":"\/business\/shopping_center","name":"Shopping center"},"Bukit Panjang Plaza",229.566818,"\/m\/02q_h6s","en"]
```

**SEARCH SAMPLE CODES**

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class SearchSample {
  public static Properties properties = new Properties();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      properties.load(new FileInputStream("freebase.properties"));
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search");


      url.put("query", "Bukit Panjang");
      //url.put("filter", "(any type:/people/person domain:location/citytown/)");
      url.put("filter", "(any part_of:singapore)");


      url.put("limit", "10");
      url.put("indent", "true");
      url.put("key", properties.get("API_KEY"));
      HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
      HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
      JSONObject response = (JSONObject)parser.parse(httpResponse.parseAsString());
      JSONArray results = (JSONArray)response.get("result");
      for (Object result : results) {
        System.out.println(JsonPath.read(result,"$.*").toString());
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `output` parameter to tailor the output, as described on this page:

https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-output

e.g.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28all+name%7Bfull%7D%3A%22Bukit+Panjang%22+part_of:singapore%29&output=%28type%29

(although you may want to consider using the `notable_type` or `notable_for` instead of raw type, depending on what your goal is)